# R sampling into groups of specific size based on count data

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to take a df as the one below and want to cut/bin/group/sample into groups of size=20.
Ideally, this "binning" occurs randomly across IDs rather then consecutively from top row to bottom row).

E.g. IDs 2, 29 and 71 have counts of 7,7,6 and would fit nicely into a "bin" of size=20.
I want to achieve the minimum number of bins and do not care about order of IDs (the more random they are, the better).

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  ID = as.numeric(1:100),
  Count = as.numeric(sample(1:8, size = 100, replace = T)))
```

Desired outcome would be a dataframe/tibble looking something like the below with optimum random sampling and minimising bin number.

Bin_size=20 is the parameter set by me (the ideal outcome is exact 20 (=20) but <20 is ok, however, >20 is not ok).
Each Bin should be given a number (e.g. if I have 10 bins, I would like them to be called Bin_number 1-10).

ID, Count, Bin_size, Bin_number

ID 2, 7, 20, 1

ID 29, 7, 20, 1

ID 71, 6, 20, 1

etc.

Where 7+7+6 = 20 (etc.)

Any help with this would be much appreciated. I have been wondering about cumsum and group_by but could not figure it out.

if you need more details, I'm happy to provide them.
thanks!

Comment: Don't understand how the `Bin_size` and `Bin_number` are defined.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am defining Bin_size=20 (just as an example). I want the count of different IDs to tally up to no more and no less than 20 (if possible). Or alternatively as close to 20 as possible (but not higher - i.e. <20 is ok but >20 is not ok). Bin_number would just be the "name/number" of the respective Bin. E.g. if I end up with 10 bins of "size" 20 they should be labelled 1-10 in the Bin_number column. Hope this clarifies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BBmisc` package has a simple (though not optimized) bin packing algorithm that might be useful:

```
library(BBmisc)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(bin = binPack(Count, 20),
         bin_size = ave(Count, bin, FUN = sum)) %>%
  arrange(bin)

# A tibble: 100 x 4
      ID Count   bin bin_size
   <dbl> <dbl> <int>    <dbl>
 1    11     4     1       20
 2    17     8     1       20
 3    27     8     1       20
 4    22     4     2       20
 5    42     8     2       20
 6    56     8     2       20
 7    34     4     3       20
 8    62     8     3       20
 9    79     8     3       20
10    40     4     4       20
# ... with 90 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you! That works great. I looked at the helper function of binPack to understand what it's doing. simple greedy algorithm is mentioned, not entirely sure what that means. Is there a way to maximise "randomness" as much as possible when picking the rose? It looks like it gives me the 4/8/8 option first, then the 7/7/6 option etc. It looks to me like it's going through the options, then takes the first rows/IDs where it sees the criterion fulfilled; E.g. 4/8/8 combination is fulfilled by rows 11,17,27 and then 22,42,56 etc. I would like to know if it is possible to randomise this picking.

Comment: Not using this particular package as far as I'm aware.  It's not at all my area but there are several other packages that offer bin packing solvers that you could investigate though it seems that the goals of random sampling and minimal bins would be in conflict.

Comment: agreed, random sampling and minimal bins would be in conflict. Not sure how to address the issue of the simple greedy algorithm, as it bunches similar sized Counts together. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this,

```
df<-df%>%arrange(Count)%>%mutate(Sum=cumsum(Count),Bin_size=20)
df<-df%>%mutate(Bin_number=cut(Sum,breaks = seq(0,c(max(Sum)+20),20),labels = F,right = T))
```